# New PrintServer object fails, "printer name is invalid"

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.printing

I'm migrating a working ASP.NET web application from WS2008R2 to WS2016, but the same happens on WS2012R2. It fails when executing:

```
new System.Printing.PrintServer(@"\\printserver");
```

It throws:

> System.Exception: An exception occurred while creating the PrintServer
> object. Win32 error: The printer name is invalid.

`printserver` is not an alias but a hostname. It loads correctly on Windows Explorer. The same line works fine on a regular Console Application when compiling under the same .NET 4.5.2, and also in PowerShell when loading the `System.Printing.dll`. The GAC shows the right assemblies, and I've also added them manually just in case.

I've set the same application pool configuration settings from the working WS2008 (disabled 32-bit applications and Classic mode), but I've tried different combinations in any case. The application pool runs under the same domain service account on both old and new.

As some user also suggested, I've installed the `Print and Document services` role, even though the old server doesn't have it, but to no avail.

I'm out of ideas, any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's possible that the print server is available to the logged-in user account, but not available to the ASP.NET service account.

Comment: The application pool is running under a domain account on both old and new server, with access to the print server.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution... But I "fixed" this by changing the path of the website in IIS manager back and forth a couple of times. Yes, after a year of trying all I could think of on several servers.

Anyway, not sure what exactly unblocked the situation, but it works for me.